# Text swatch is rendered as image - why?

Tags: magento2, swatches

Magento 2.4.6

I have two product attributes, both are text swatches used on a product.

One of them is rendered as an image with the class `swatch-option image`
while the other is rendered as `swatch-option text`.

I just can't figure out why one is rendered as an image ... they look the same and are definitely text swatches. Is there a way to force them not to be rendered as image? What could be the reason for that behaviour?

Thanks!